# Xamarin Forms Json Desrialization

Tags: json, xamarin, serialization, xamarin.forms, mobile

I want to deserialize a JSON coming from a web service, but for some reason I am getting an exception. I searched every question related to this topic but I did not find anything related to this exception. What might me the problem? here is the exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected token while deserializing object: EndObject. Path '', line 1, position 243.'
```

Here is my deserialize method:

```
        public async Task<LoginApiResponse> AuthenticateUserAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        
      //  try
      //  {
            LoginApiRequest loginRequest = new LoginApiRequest()
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = password
            };

            // serialize object to json
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await Client.PostAsync(Constants.LOGIN_URI, content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            // get the data on success and serialize it from json
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var json = new JsonTextReader(reader))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + Serializer.Deserialize<LoginApiResponse>(json));
                return Serializer.Deserialize<LoginApiResponse>(json);
            }
       // }
  /*      catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }*/
    }
```

here is the Request model:

```
    public class LoginApiRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public LoginApiRequest() { }
}
```

here is the Response Model:

```
public class LoginApiResponse : MessageStatus
{
    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public User Data { get; set; }
    public LoginApiResponse() { }
}
```

here is the User model:

```
    public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("BloodType")]
    public string BloodType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ConfirmPassword")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CustomerID")]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DOB")]
    public string DOB { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("UserRoleID")]
    public int? UserRoleID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public User() { }
}
```

and here is the the messagestatus:

```
    public class MessageStatus
{
    [JsonProperty("Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public MessageStatus() { }
}
```

and finally here is the json:

```
{
    "Message": null,
    "Status": 1,
    "Data": {
        "Address": "Beirut",
        "BloodType": null,
        "ConfirmPassword": null,
        "CustomerID": null,
        "DOB": null,
        "Email": null,
        "ID": 22,
        "IsActive": true,
        "Name": "tg",
        "Password": "123456",
        "Phone": "03708424",
        "UserRoleID": 1,
        "Username": "tg"
    }
}
```

Comment: are you **positive** that is the actual json response your app is receiving, and that there are no extraneous characters?  Have you tried reading as a string and deserializing instead of using a stream?

Comment: @Jason yeah it has to be it, i got this json from postman by calling the same url from my code, how can I get the json  as string to check?

Comment: use`ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: @Jason ok will check and get back to  you :)

Comment: @Json got this exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "Message" to type 'DeliveryApplication.Models.Login.LoginApiResponse'. Path '', line 1, position 10.'

Comment: I have no idea what changes you've made to your code to get this error

Comment: @Json I only printed the json using : json.ReadAsStringAsync(); I did not change anything

Comment: I was suggesting you read the json as a string and deserialize it **instead** of what you're doing now that requires three using statements.  Replace `ReadAsStreamAsync` with `ReadAsStringAsync`

Comment: @Jason dude you are my hero!!!!! Thank you!!

Comment: @Jason can u please explain why reading it as string worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var json = new JsonTextReader(reader))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + Serializer.Deserialize<LoginApiResponse>(json));
            return Serializer.Deserialize<LoginApiResponse>(json);
        }
```

try

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginApiResponse>(json)
return data;
```

Comment: thank u again. but why this worked? although the one I watched his tutorial used the stream method and it worked

Comment: without actually debugging your code I can't say for sure.  But I generally always use `DeserializeObject` with a `string` instead of using `streams`